# node.js app not auto-updating with iisnode

Tags: node.js, iisnode

My node.js app doesn't seem to auto-update when I make a change to my app.js file and save it, even after the default 60,000ms. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the watchedFiles attribute in iisnode.yml (https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/iisnode.yml#L68) or web.config (https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config#L123) to explicitly list app.js?

If that does not help please open an issue at https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/new (and post back the link here for cross-reference).

Comment: Hi Tomasz, tried setting the attribute but it didn't work. Will go ahead and open the issue. Thanks again for your help.